# Error // uninitialized constant Sass::Rails::Application (NameError)] // when running 'rails server'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I go to run the server I receive this error:

```
C:\Users\myusername\sass>rails server
C:/Users/myusername/sass/config/application.rb:13:in `<module:Sass>': uninitialized 
constant Sass::Rails::Application (NameError)
        from C:/Users/myusername/sass/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)
>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:53:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:50:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sass` is a Ruby library and incidentally it is also used by Ruby. You should use a different name for your Rails app.

Run the generator again and chose a different name, such as `myproject` or anything else (except Ruby modules).

Comment: Ahh perfect that's what I was wondering ...it's a reserved word. Thank you so much for you feedback Simone I'll try test app and see.

Comment: Yes that worked. Thanks again!  So everyone to else having issues... When naming apps, don't use Rails or Ruby library names as they are reserved words.